# EE solution for image-zooming on hover?

Tags: image, image-galleries

I'd like to do something like at http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom, zooming into an image on hover. Is there a preferred/popular way of doing this in EE? Any recommended software?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about front end dev, not EECMS.

Comment: I was hoping for an EE add-on that could put together a gallery with zoom abilities.

Comment: EE usually don't have such low level add-ons. It is give you a freedom make any frontend solution very fast. It is question of 10-15 min to make it w/o any EE addons (just use native channel or/and grid), just use the same frontend script which mention in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Image zooming is a front-end/template issue, so you can do whatever you want. Just follow the instructions of the jQuery plugin you want to use.